# phpmailer and gmail SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Network is unreachable (101) SMTP connect() failed

Tags: smtp, gmail, phpmailer

I need help please
this is my code:

```
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->Port = 587;

$mail->Username = 'some@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = 'somepass';
$mail->addAddress('another@gmail.com', 'Josh Adams');
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer GMail SMTP test';
$body = 'This is the HTML message body in bold!';
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
```

and I get this error:
**2013-12-11 15:15:02 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Network is unreachable (101) SMTP connect() failed. Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.**

any help please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might want to start by isolating this problem to determine whether it's truly a network problem; or whether it's specific to PHP mailer or your code.  On your server, from a command prompt, try using telnet to connect to smtp.gmail.com on port 587, like so:

```
telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
```

You should see a response from smtp.gmail.com, like so:

```
Trying 173.194.74.108...
Connected to gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mx.google.com ESMTP f19sm71757226qaq.12 - gsmtp
```

Do you see this, or does the connection attempt hang and eventually time out?  If the connection fails, it could mean that your hosting company is blocking outgoing SMTP connections on port 587.

Comment: I have received same response with 220 code, it means SMTP is allowed on server. Then why am I getting error 'SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Network is unreachable (101) SMTP connect() failed. Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.' 

**What else can I check or what are the reasons of this connection failed? **

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

change:

```
  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
  $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
  $mail->Port = '465';
```

to

```
  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
  $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
  $mail->Port = '587';
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->Host = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465';
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issues on Godaddy hosting so I spend lots of time and fix it by disabling the SMTP restriction on the server end.

SMTP code is for PHPMailer

```
 $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    //$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                       //Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                       //Enable verbose debug output           
    //$mail->isSMTP();                                             //Send using SMTP

    $mail->Host         = "tls://smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->SMTPAuth     = true;
    $mail->Username     = contact@example.in;
    $mail->Password     = SMTP_PASSWORD;
    $mail->SMTPSecure   = "tls";
    $mail->Port         = 587;
    $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
        'ssl' => array(
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
            'allow_self_signed' => true
        )
    );
    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('contact@example.in', 'Online Order');
    $mail->addAddress('test@gmail.com');     //Add a recipient
    $mail->addReplyTo('contact@example.in', 'Jewellery');
   

    //Attachments
    //$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         //Add attachments
    //$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    //Optional name

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Order';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is test email content';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is test email content';

    if($mail->send()){
        return '1';                 
    }else{
        return 'Order email sending failed';
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score -3):

change

`$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";`

with

`$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';`

Comment: Where does this come from? He has Port Settings 587, so that's meant to be TLS/STARTTLS. SMTP SSL has usually Port 465 and SMTP TLS/STARTTLS 587 (except if you are using some fancy (not understandably) internal port mappings on your server).