# PhpMailer is not working on live server

Tags: phpmailer

PhpMailer is working fine in localhost. But when I've uploaded it on a live server it is not working.

> SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Network is unreachable
>   (101) 
> The following From address failed: facefinder2@gmail.com :
>   Called Mail() without being connected Mailer Error: The following From
>   address failed: facefinder2@gmail.com : Called Mail() without being
>   connected

I'm using the following code:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP(); 
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = '587';
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'facefinder2@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = '************';
$mail->SetFrom("facefinder2@gmail.com");
//$mail->FromName = "FaceFinder";

$mail->addAddress($receiver, $name);

$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $body;
$mail->AltBody = $plain_body;

if(!$mail->send()) {
    //return false;
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo; die();
} else {
    return true;
    //echo "Message has been sent successfully";
}
```

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Are you by any chance on GoDaddy? This exact scenario is covered in the [PHPMailer troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting). The fact that your error message does not include a link to that suggests that you're using an old version. The posted answer is correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [phpmailer and gmail SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Network is unreachable (101) SMTP connect() failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20523285/phpmailer-and-gmail-smtp-error-failed-to-connect-to-server-network-is-unreacha)

Answer (score 0):

> Failed to connect to server: Network is unreachable (101)

It seems your hosting environment is blocking outbound connection to gmail (either by domain or port) which tends to happen when using shared hosting (spam prevention).

Basically you have to check with your service provider