# Unable to send email in PHPMailer using Gmail SMTP. Getting Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. How to fix this?

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail

I have this script to send mails with Gmail SMTP:

```
require 'mailPhp/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    $email= $_POST['Email'];
    echo $email;
    $clientFolder= $GLOBALS['directory'];
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';                       // Specify main and backup server
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'user@gmail.com';                   // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'password';               // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted
    $mail->Port = 465;                                    //Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS
    $mail->setFrom('contact@azura-space.com', 'Fuyor Romania');     //Set who the message is to be sent from
    $mail->addReplyTo('contact@bocher.us', 'Comenzi Fuyor Romania');  //Set an alternative reply-to address
    $mail->addAddress("$email");  // Add a recipient
    $mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
    // $mail->addAttachment('/usr/labnol/file.doc');         // Add attachments
    $mail->addAttachment("$clientFolder/file.pdf", 'DeliveryOrder.pdf');
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

    $mail->Subject = 'Comanda Fuyor';
    $mail->Body    = 'Va multumim ca ati cumparat de la noi. V-am trimis o copie 
                      dupa comanda dvs in acest mail.';

    if(!$mail->send()) {
       echo 'Message could not be sent.';
       echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
       exit;
    }

    echo 'Message has been sent';
```

This is working fine if it runs from an HTTP domain, but when I put it on an https domain it gives me this error:
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Also, I tried to change the secure method and port from TLS 587 to SSL 465 but is not working. The script is identical on both domains...
Where is the problem?

Comment: Try this: 1. Add `$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;` to see if there is any further messages; 2. Test it on a different IP (Your own laptop) address, maybe your server is blocked by Google

Comment: Yes, i have this one   SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Network is unreachable (101)

Comment: Seems that you have the connectivity issue. Check if you can `ping smtp.gmail.com` on the machine where your code runs.

Comment: PING gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com (173.194.79.108) 56(84) bytes of data.          
64 bytes from eg-in-f108.1e100.net (173.194.79.108): icmp_seq=1 ttl=47 time=10.0 ms. Thanks for helping me

Comment: then see what's the output of `telnet smtp.gmail.com 465`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [phpmailer and gmail SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Network is unreachable (101) SMTP connect() failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20523285/phpmailer-and-gmail-smtp-error-failed-to-connect-to-server-network-is-unreacha)

Comment: I have my domain host on a shared hosting, so i have acces only to a cpanel.This is because i need a secure domain to acces my script from shopify.I don`t have acces to a console.My mistake for the first ping...sorry

Comment: Might be your hosting provider blocks the outgoing connection to gmail. You might contact your hosting provider to check if they blocked or not. Or you can use `$output = shell_exec("telnet smtp.gmail.com 465")` in php.

Comment: thank you, sir!! I moved my php script to another domain :D thanks a lot for helping me

Comment: worked? Great. Maybe the hosting provider worries about its customers abuse its network for sending spams